# Are Azure Blobs encrypted when they are stored in Microsoft?

Tags: security, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a site that stores text in Azure Blob Storage. The text may be sensitive (not necessarily passwords, but personal information).  I am trying to decide whether or not I should encrypt the text before I store it in Azure Blob Storage.  My understanding is that this could mitigate a risk of exposing the data should the Azure key and account name get out and a malicious user download the blob.  My questions are:

- Are Azure Blobs *already* being encrypted when they land on disk at Microsoft?  Is the account key used as an encryption key, or just an access token?
- IF I were to do this in Azure Websites by using the .NET AES algorithm, where should I store the encryption key(s) or passphrase/salt used to generate a key?  (ie is web.config an ok place for this?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Blob content is not encrypted; that step would be completely up to you. Blob access is strictly controlled by access key (and there are two keys: primary and secondary, both working equally). Here are my thoughts on this:

- If Storage access is exclusive to your app tier (that is, the key is never exposed outside of your app), risk is fairly low (vs. embedding the key in a desktop or mobile app, or using it with online storage browser services). Someone would need to steal the key from you somehow (like stealing source / config files). You mentioned using Websites, which doesn't provide RDP access, further protecting your running code.
- If, somehow, your key were compromised, you can invalidate the key by generating a new one. This immediately cuts off access to anyone holding the old key. As a general pattern, when I use external tools (such as the Cerebrata tool), I always use my *secondary* key, reserving my *primary* key for my app. That way, I can always invalidate my secondary key as often as I like, preventing these tools from accessing my storage but not interfering with my running apps.
- If you need to expose specific blobs to your customers, you have two ways to do it. First, you can download the blob to your web server, and then stream content down. Second: You can generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) for the specific blob, and then give that resultant URI to the user (e.g. as the `href` of of an `<a>` tag). By using SAS, you permit access to a private blob for a given amount of time, like 10-20 minutes. Even if someone took an SAS URL and posted it on the Internet, it would only be valid for the time window you specified (it's hashed, preventing modification).
- Consider multiple storage accounts for multiple apps (or even per app). This way, if there *were* a security breach, damage is limited to the specific compromised storage account.

**EDIT April 2016**

Azure Storage Service encryption for data at rest, just announced, is now in preview and available for any storage account created via the Azure Resource Manager (ARM). It is not available for "Classic" storage accounts (the rest of my answer, above, still applies). You can enable/disable encryption via the portal, for your storage account:

[image: storage encryption in portal]

The service is available for blobs in both standard and premium storage accounts. More details are in [this post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-service-encryption/).

Comment: We should probably update this answer to include the new Azure Storage Service Encryption features, which were not available at the time this was posted.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-service-encryption/

Comment: As this answer is very much outdated by now (even with the update regarding encryption in preview), should the whole answer be re-written? This thread ranks quite high in google searches and many people will still land here. It should include information about things like encryption at rest is on by default and you can also use your own keys these days (BYOK)

Answer (score 6):

David's answer is spot-on, but for people looking to actually implement the encryption the poster asked about, I've put together some samples and libraries at [Azure Encryption Extensions](https://github.com/stefangordon/azure-encryption-extensions).

Comment: +1 Are there any downsides to encrypting on the fly when uploading/downloading from blob storage? E.g. Transfer time take longer?