# Create an encrypted bacpac file in Azure

Tags: azure, encryption, azure-sql-database, bacpac

Currently we have a requirement to create bacpac file for the databases hosted in Azure MI and most importantly the bacpac file needs to be in encrypted format.

We thought the following two ideas:

1. Perform Bacpac to local storage(Disk drive) and then perform AZCopy to Azure storage. But the problem here is file will not be in encrypted format during the brief time of copy.
2. I read that Azure storage container has encryption by default but I don't see a method to run SQLPACKAGE.exe with target as Azure Storage.

So can you please advise on the possible options here to create an encrypted bacpac file?

Answer (score 0):

We can not create the  encrypted .bacpac file directly. Others have asked this question before.

Actually, Blob content is not encrypted; that step would be completely up to you. You could reference this blog: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17170530/10549281.

The best way to create an encrypted .bacpac is using Azure Key Vault in Azure blob. We create the bacpac file from Azure MI to Blob Storage, then using the Azure Key Vault feature to make it be an encrypted .bacpac.

Reference:

1. [Tutorial - Encrypt and decrypt blobs using Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault)
2. [Encrypt dacpac/bacpac file](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/7ecc9439-a2b8-4c4d-84cc-055e5c603e4f/encrypt-dacpacbacpac-file)

Hope this helps.